# why to divide by counts for getting probability density function

Tags: python, histogram, probability-density

```
count, bin_edges = np.histogram(iris_setosa['petal_length'], bins=10, 
                             density = True)
```

i have found this code for getting probability density function. as i set density =True,then the count must be in normalized form i.e between the range of 0 to 1. but i get the output :
count:(array([0.22222222, 0.22222222, 0.44444444, 1.55555556, 2.88888889 2.88888889, 1.55555556, 0.88888889, 0.0, 0.44444444])

then to calculate pdf, i found the following code

```
pdf=count/sum(count)
```

why we are dividing by count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Density by definition requires some kind of normalization. We generally need density of something to get an idea about how a small part of the whole system works. Like for density of a physical object, we need to divide the mass by the whole volume, which gives the 'uniformed' mass of an unit volume. 
Similarly if we divide individual probability by the sum of all we get the 'density' of probabilities which connects a smaller system to the whole system.